# Telerik reporting barcode extra character at the end when scanning

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, reporting, barcode-scanner, telerik-reporting

Original

[image: Original barcode]

after scanning

[image: after scanning extra character at end]

**Note:** Iam using telerik report Q2 version and number with code39 format
**Issue:** telerik reporting barcode after scanning extra character added at end of the number how to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by setting Checksum property to  false now working fine.

[image]